# Any chance to hover on element for specific time?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to mouse hover on element , first time it hover properly and hold but then never it does same. I can see that it is trying to hold hover but runs too fast and effect comes like just blink on element.

My code :

```
WebElement hover =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frmDashboard']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a"));

 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

I have tried all type of wait , sleep methods here but no success.

Comment: Do you have a sample URL where the effect is noticeable?

Comment: @FDM - yes see here example URL : http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-menu-with-submenu-using-css-html/26146      Here submenu opens when we hover on main menu so if we do code it works 1-2 times only. To pick submenu using webdriver action is not always success here that I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sample URL you have provided, the below **C#** code appears to work every time for me (four attempts).

Of course, I'm not hovering for a specific time (why would you?) but in this case until a new element becomes visible.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, please provide more feedback and the actual code and HTML.

```
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-menu-with-submenu-using-css-html/26146");

            IWebElement lnk_mainMenu_Channel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='http://mrbool.com/articles/listcomp.asp' and @class='menulink']"));
            IWebElement lnk_subMenu_Mobile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='submenu']//a[@href='http://mrbool.com/channel/mobile']"));
            w.Until(d => lnk_mainMenu_Channel.Displayed);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(lnk_mainMenu_Channel).Perform();
            w.Until(d => lnk_subMenu_Mobile.Displayed);
            action.MoveToElement(lnk_subMenu_Mobile).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: ok let me try in this way..

Comment: No it's just a random variable (C# stuff). In Java, you can use an ExpectedCondition.isElementVisible (or something like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked... I think displayed worked here..

Answer (score 2):

I haven't succeeded in hovering either, but if hovering is needed for example to make some element visible, you can simulate the effect with this kind of javascript construction:

```
driver.execute_script(
    "$('.my_class').css('display','inline-block')")
```

This would make the element with class "my_class" accessible.

Comment: Thanks for solution , but I am looking for specific hover with webdriver..